# Regional Sales Tax on PayPal Subscriptions React-js

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am integrating PayPal subscriptions and one-time payment. What I am looking for is to apply regional sales taxes on subscriptions/billing_agreements, but as per my understanding subscription plans can have a fixed tax that can not be overwritten while signing billing agreement. Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Create a copy of the Plan for each region, each with its own tax
2. Have the Plan tax amount be 0, and calculate a `shipping_amount` when creating the subscription: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_create